# UITableView background does not set

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have this code inside the viewDidLoad (putting that inside the viewDidAppear didn't work either).

```
  UIView *texturedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    texturedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundLeather.png"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = texturedBackgroundView;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

But I cannot see any background as an image. It is completely white - like no image is set. Why is that?

Please note that, my tableview has it's own controller - which is initialised like this :

```
AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
PAPHomeViewController *vc = del.homeViewController;
vc.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
[self.containerView addSubview:vc.view];
[self addChildViewController:vc];
```

So, it is like I see the background of the containerView and not the background of the tableview.

Trying that didn't help it :

```
[self.containerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: You don't see your image even if you pull down the table view so you can see above the first cell? If so, then you should check to see that [UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundLeather.png"] is returning an image. You should also check whether self.tableView is nil.

Comment: @rdelmar yes, even if I pull down is white - not even behind the cell. imageNamed was returning null - problem solved. Make it an answer and I will accept it.